# chunk processing in a loop

Tags: modx-revolution

I'm having the following code which unfortunately returns the same and not updated chunk in foreach loop. The retrieved chunk contains some placeholders which need to be updated with each record. Doeas anyone have an idea why? I use getObject and process it instead of using getChunk because the first one is a bit faster.

```
$chunkie = $modx->getObject('modChunk', array('name' => 'thumbTemplate'));
foreach ($items as $item) {

        $itemArray = $item->toArray();
        $itemArray['idx'] = $idx;
        (...)

$output .= $chunkie->process($itemArray);
$idx++;
};
```

Comment: The general idea is that the snippet loops and foreach item displays values in a chunk which gets placeholder values. I need to speed up the process by setting the chunk and not getting it every time in a foreach loop-that's a waste of time. Apporx 4 sec/100 loops

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve the chunk inside your loop...

```
//$chunkie = $modx->getObject('modChunk', array('name' => 'thumbTemplate'));

foreach ($items as $item) {

    $itemArray = $item->toArray();

    $itemArray['idx'] = $idx;

    (...)

    $output .= $modx->getChunk('thumbTemplate',$itemArray);

    $idx++;

};
```

not sure if you can use the getObject method to populate your chunk placeholders as well. [actually I'm kinda sure you can't]

**UPDATE**

try this:

```
<?php
$output = '';

$items = array(
    'apples'=>'bananas',
    'orange'=>'orange juice',
    'peaches'=>'peach cobbler'
    );

// use a query to retrieve your actual chunk from the db
$tpl = '[[+key]] = [[+value]] <br />';


foreach ($items as $key => $value) {

    $itemArray = array(
        'key'=>$key,
        'value'=>$value
    );

    $chunkie = $modx->newObject('modChunk');
    $chunkie->setContent($tpl);

    $output .= $chunkie->process($itemArray);

};

return $output;
```

obviously I made some small changes so we could cut & paste & see working, just adapt the main parts to your code.

Comment: This method obviously works but I want to omit retrieving the chunk over and over again. I would rather like to get the chunk before the foreach and populate it using the foreach loop. This way I can save a lot of processing time especially when there is 100+ records to output using the mentioned chunk

Comment: Do you get the same result using the getChunk method outside your loop? Seems to me like your method should work. Can we see the full code? maybe something else is happening here.

Comment: I don't think the whole code is needed cause the snippet does different things which don't affect the iteration. I have never used the getChunk outside the foreach loop cause I need to pass an array to it which is generated inside the loop. I was following the suggestions from this link but with no luck-maybe you have some clue: http://forums.modx.com/thread/74071/help-with-getchunk-and-modx-speed-please?page=4#dis-post-440130

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I think this would be the fastest way that will still update the placeholders:

```
$chunkId = 12; // id of the stored chunk
$chunk = $modx->getObject('modchunk', $chunkId);

/* If you use getChunk(), the placeholders will be processed, 
   which you don't want */
$content = $chunk->getContent();

$tempChunk = $modx->newObject('modChunk');

/* This might have to go in the loop */
$tempChunk->setCacheable(false);

foreach ($items as $item) {
   $itemArray = $item->toArray();
   $itemArray['idx'] = $idx;
   // (...)
   $tempChunk->setContent($content);
   $tempChunk->setProperties($itemArray);

   $output .= $tempChunk->process();
   $idx++;
}
```